# Date and time from hex

Tags: datetime, format, timestamp, hex

I'm trying to read public transport cards and I've figured out the data format mostly but the record dates and times are a mystery. Some data:

```
e1 a2 00 00 ce 04 05 b1 7e 00 68 22 0a 10 00 ce - 01.03.2014 23:36
e4 a2 00 00 ce 04 e5 7b 7e 00 e4 2e 0a 10 00 e9 - 04.03.2014 16:31
e4 a2 00 00 4c 04 43 8c d0 07 30 00 01 00 00 72 - 04.03.2014 18:42
e4 a2 00 00 ce 04 65 8d 7e 00 7c 17 0a 10 00 a2 - 04.03.2014 18:51
ea a2 00 00 ce 04 25 63 7e 00 70 09 0a 10 00 f1 - 10.03.2014 13:13
ec a2 00 00 ce 04 25 63 7e 00 70 09 0a 10 00 da - 12.03.2014 13:13
f3 a2 00 00 ce 04 85 69 7e 00 64 3b 0a 10 00 9d - 19.03.2014 14:04
f5 a2 00 00 ce 04 e5 89 7e 00 70 22 0a 10 00 ba - 21.03.2014 18:23
f6 a2 00 00 ce 04 6a 00 82 01 68 22 2a 10 00 df - 22.03.2014 00:03
fb a2 00 00 ce 04 85 75 7e 00 84 17 0a 10 00 2a - 27.03.2014 15:40
fb a2 00 00 ce 04 a5 91 7e 00 78 17 0a 10 00 a6 - 27.03.2014 19:25

c1 a2 28 00 ce 04 0b 6b 00 00 74 17 08 10 04 94 - 28.01.2014 14:16
c7 a2 00 00 ce 04 a5 5d 7e 00 6c 09 0a 10 00 1b - 03.02.2014 12:29
c7 a2 00 00 ce 04 25 6c 7e 00 68 2d 0a 10 00 68 - 03.02.2014 14:25
c7 a2 0e 00 ce 04 eb 6d 00 00 88 17 08 10 04 45 - 03.02.2014 14:39
ce a2 00 00 ce 04 85 52 7e 00 68 09 0a 10 00 77 - 10.02.2014 11:00
ce a2 00 00 ce 04 e5 5c 7e 00 64 09 0a 10 00 58 - 10.02.2014 12:23
eb a2 00 00 ce 04 85 41 7e 00 80 22 0a 10 00 dd - 11.03.2014 08:44
eb a2 00 00 ce 04 85 6a 7e 00 a4 28 0a 10 00 66 - 11.03.2014 14:12
eb a2 20 00 ce 04 8b 6e 00 00 7c 17 08 10 04 e0 - 11.03.2014 14:44
|| ||             || || ** **    ** **    **
Date?             Time?
```

Stars represent known data (as in I know what those mean and they aren't relevant to date and time)

Provided dates are correct, because they're from usage history printout.

I've tried converting values to unix timestamps, seconds, milliseconds and much more, but I can't determine the format. Also the data might be in little endian.
I'm not sure about possible timezone, data might be in UTC, UTC+2 or UTC+3.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Do you know which time zone the date/time values are reported in? Is it UTC or some other non-zero offset from UTC?  Do you have any more diverse records — for February or April, for example, or for any dates last year?

Comment: I edited the post. Sadly I don't have any data from last year. Time might be in UTC+2 or +3 because of daylight saving time.

Comment: Urgh; with the extra data, there go most of my theories, which were pretty whacko anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the format, it goes like this:

All data is in little endian.

To get the time in minutes, the value must be bitsifted to right five times.
For example:

```
6e8b >> 5 = 884
```

884 minutes = 14 hours, 44 minutes (14:44)

Date is days from 1.1.1900. For example:

```
a2eb = 41707 (11.03.2014)
```